# store values of structure in entity using outsystems

Tags: outsystems

I want store values of structure in an entity.
     I created one structure and assigned some variable values to structure attributes using outsystems. So I want store that structure attribute values in an entity.Please help me.
Thanks 
In advance

Comment: Please provide sample code that demonstrates what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the purpose of the structure that you created is to be stored in the database as an entity, then the structure is unnecessary. For instance if you have an `User` entity, you don't need to create a structure to hold a User's information: you can create variables that are of type `User` and assign values directly to those variables' attributes.

This is to say that perhaps you don't need a structure at all. If that's the case you can:

- create a variable
- set the variable `type` property to your entity
- assign the attributes using an `Assign` node (eg: setting `yourVariable.yourAttribute` to the respective value)
- use the built-in action `Create<YourEntity>` to store the variable in the database

If you do need a structure for some reason, you can still follow the steps above but use the structure's attributes as values that feed the variable in the assign node.

Comment: Its very useful Miguel Ventura